# Error: Address not available when running mosquitto using docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, mosquitto

I recently installed the mosquitto library using homebrew and wrote a docker-compose file as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mqtt:
      container_name: MQTT
      image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.18
      #restart: always
      ports:
        - "1883:1883"
        - "9001:9001"         
      volumes:
        - ./mosquitto:/mosquitto/config
         - mqtt-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
      networks:
        - vision-net  

  odm:
      container_name: ODM
      image: opendronemap/nodeodm:3.3.5
      #restart: always
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      networks:
        - vision-net  

volumes:
  mqtt-data:
networks:
  vision-net: {}
```

However running it on my macbook m1 I the the following trace:

```
MQTT  | 1705485512: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
MQTT  | 1705485512: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
MQTT  | 1705485512: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
MQTT  | 1705485512: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
MQTT  | 1705485512: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
MQTT  | 1705485512: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
MQTT  | 1705485512: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
MQTT  | 1705485512: Error: Address not available
MQTT  | 1705485512: mosquitto version 2.0.18 running
```

What could be the issue?